# Error in opening a SDP file using libavcodec

Tags: ffmpeg, udp, streaming, libavcodec, libavformat

I tried to open a SDP file using the following coed using libavcodec commands:

```
 char *url = "foo.sdp";
 AVFormatContext *oc = NULL;
 avformat_open_input(&oc, url, NULL , NULL);
```

where the content of "foo.sdp" is as follows:

```
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=No Name
c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
t=0 0
a=tool:libavformat 55.22.100
m=video 1234 RTP/AVP 96
b=AS:200
a=rtpmap:96 MP4V-ES/90000
a=fmtp:96 profile-level-id=1
```

but when I execute this code, I get the following error:

```
[udp @ 0049e6e0] bind failed: Error number -10048 occurred
```

Do you know what is the problem, and how I can solve it? Thanks!

Comment: This question is old and unanswered. Have you had some more success in the meantime?